# Alfred keeps asking for Contacts permission

Tags: macos, contacts, system-settings, software, alfred

I'm not sure what is going on. Every time I access Alfred, I get this dialog box, "Alfred would like to access your contacts." I always have to click "OK" before I can use the program. I have verified that the Alfred checkbox is checked in the Contacts settings in System Preferences. Does anyone have any other ideas?

[image: Alfred]

Comment: You may want to consider asking the question here http://www.alfredforum.com/forum/2-v2-discussion-help/

Answer (score 13):

Just like [@nobody-in-particular said](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/120050), your Alfred code was probably changed, therefore the signature that was in place for Alfred is no longer valid. What you have to do is sign the application after the changes to the code.

This worked for me:

```
sudo codesign --force --deep --sign - "/Applications/Alfred 2.app/Contents/Frameworks/Alfred Framework.framework/Versions/A/Alfred Framework"
```

Comment: still working on alfred 3. change app name like that : sudo codesign --force --deep --sign - "/Applications/Alfred 3.app/Contents/Frameworks/Alfred Framework.framework/Versions/A/Alfred Framework"

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Alfred version 2.1.1?

If you open Alfred Preferences and check the Features pane you can click on Contacts and try toggling ‘Open Contacts in Alfred’.

You might also try checking the Workflows pane and see if you have any workflows using Contacts.

Answer (score 0):

Is your copy of Alfred properly licensed, or pirated?  I'll admit that mine was pirated, and the newest cracked version kept asking for contacts, presumably because the code signing required for the Mac Store also applies to contact permissions.  If the code is changed (which it is in the cracking process) Apple's contact permissions API will need to continually ask for permission, since it doesn't recognize the program.  You might try Quicksilver instead; it's like Alfred but free and does more, although it's also more complicated and less shiny.

Answer (score 0):

Try running these commands in Terminal:

```
sqlite3 ~/Library/Application\ Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db
sqlite> INSERT or REPLACE INTO access values ('kTCCServiceAddressBook','com.runningwithcrayons.Alfred-2', 0, 1, 0, NULL);
sqlite> .exit
```

Comment: what's that do?

Comment: As l'L'L put it, please provide an explanation or reference of these commands that you are asking the OP to enter so that your answer becomes more credible.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into Privacy Services Manager coming out of the University of Utah: https://github.com/univ-of-utah-marriott-library-apple/privacy_services_manager
Once you're set up, Terminal command: privacy_services_manager.py add contacts /Applications/Chess.app